# Failed to remove custom role definition - existing role assignments

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

I have a custom role and there are no assignments as far as I know. But I am unable to delete it.
Check screenshot below.

The error says `There are existing role assignments referencing role. The role assingments must be deleted before the role can be deleted.`

[image]

This is the IAM controls at subscription level. It shows there are 0 assignments at the bottom.

Does anyone know why I cannot delete it?
Is there a way to see if there is actually some asignee for that role?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try running the [Get-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-4.4.0) Powershell command to return all the assignments.  It's possible there is an assignment to an ID or resource that has been deleted such it is orphaned.

To accomplish this first run:

```
connect-azaccount
```

This will prompt you to log into Azure.  After such then switch to the subscription you are looking to run by [Select-AzureSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/select-azuresubscription?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) like:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName <SUBSCRIPTION NAME>
```

Then run the Get-AzRoleAssignment like:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinition ROLENAME
```

If this returns a list then run the [Remove-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azroleassignment?view=azps-4.4.0) for each Object ID returned:

```
Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment-ObjectId <Guid>
```